# How to group by in jq?

Tags: json, linux, group-by, jq

Here's the json document

```
[
    {"name": "bucket1","clusterName":"cluster1"},
    {"name": "bucket2","clusterName":"cluster1"},
    {"name": "bucket3","clusterName":"cluster2"},
    {"name": "bucket4","clusterName":"cluster2"}
]
```

And I want to convert it to

```
[
{"clusterName": "cluster1", buckets:[{"name": "bucket1"}, {"name": "bucket2"}]},
{"clusterName": "cluster2", buckets:[{"name": "bucket1"}, {"name": "bucket2"}]},
]
```

How do I do that in jq?

Comment: Looks on-topic to me: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368711/are-sed-awk-and-text-processing-questions-valid-on-stack-overflow-anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat doc.json | jq '[group_by(.clusterName)[] | { clusterName: .[0].clusterName, "buckets": [.[] | { name: .name } ]}]'
```

Should do what you want.
Now with an array around as well.

Comment: Ahh, no - it doesn't wrap in an array - I will update in a minute.

Comment: Thank you. This is brilliant. This is working so far. I am testing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` makes for quite a tidy answer:

```
group_by(.clusterName)
| map( {clusterName: .[0].clusterName,
        buckets: map( {name} ) } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` and based on [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60013574/1037626)'s answer, I needed all the bucket names in an array:

```
jq 'group_by(.clusterName) | map( { clusterName : .[0].clusterName, buckets: [ .[].name ] } )'
```

gives:

```
[
  {
    "clusterName": "cluster1",
    "buckets": [
      "bucket1",
      "bucket2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "clusterName": "cluster2",
    "buckets": [
      "bucket3",
      "bucket4"
    ]
  }
]
```