# JSON jq/python file manipulation with specific key name aggregation

Tags: python, arrays, json, bash, jq

I need to modify the structure of this json file:

```
[
   {
      "id":"3333",
      "properties":{
         "label":"Computer",
         "name":"My-Laptop"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":"9998",
      "type":"file_system",
      "properties":{
         "mount_point":"/opt",
         "name":"/dev/mapper/rhel-opt",
         "root_container":"3333"
      },
      "label":"FileSystem"
   },
   {
      "id":"9999",
      "type":"file_system",
      "properties":{
         "mount_point":"/var",
         "name":"/dev/mapper/rhel-var",
         "root_container":"3333"
      },
      "label":"FileSystem"
   }
]
```

in order to have this kind of output:

```
[
   {
      "id":"3333",
      "properties":{
         "label":"Computer",
         "name":"My-Laptop",
         "file_system":[
            "/opt",
            "/var"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

The idea is to have, in the new json structure, the visibility of my laptop with the two file-system partition in an array named "file_system".
As you can see the two partition are related to the first by the `id` and `root_container`.
So, imagine to have not only one laptop, bat thousands of laptop, with different `id` and every one of these have different partition, related to the laptop by the `root_container` key.

Is there an option to do this with `jq` functions or `python` script?
Many thanks

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60011507/how-to-group-by-in-jq

Comment: Based on your sample data, where does `/var` come from?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:python] if you want a [tag:jq] solution? What did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: I add python as possible solutions. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You could employ `reduce` to iterate over the items while extracting their `id`, `mount_point` and `root_container`. Then, if a `root_container` was present, delete that entry and add its `mount_point` to the entry whose `id` matches their `root_container`. For convenience, I also employed `INDEX` on the items' `id` fields to simplify their access as `.[$id]` and `.[$root_container]`, which had to be undone at the end using `map(.)`.

```sh
jq '
  reduce .[] as {$id, properties: {$mount_point, $root_container}} (
    INDEX(.id);
    if $root_container then
      del(.[$id])
      | .[$root_container].properties.file_system += [$mount_point]
    else . end
  )
  | map(.)
'
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": "3333",
    "properties": {
      "label": "Computer",
      "name": "My-Laptop",
      "file_system": [
        "/opt",
        "/var"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/L74vx5AGpKV)